# Async/Await doesn't work in a recursive function

Tags: node.js, recursion, promise

I'm struggling with a "Promise" problem.

I have this code:

```
let createCategoryRoot = await categoryService.createCategory(rootCategory.title);
let setExternalIdRoot = await categoryService.setExternalId(createCategoryRoot.body.version, createCategoryRoot.body.id, rootCategory.categoryid);        
await createTree(rootCategory, setExternalIdRoot);
return true;
```

This is the *createTree* function (recursive):

```
async function createTree(rootCategory, setExternalIdRoot) {
  try {
    if(rootCategory.children !== undefined && rootCategory.children.category !== undefined){
      if (rootCategory.children.category.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rootCategory.children.category.length; i++) {
          let child = rootCategory.children.category[i];
          let createCategory = await categoryService.createCategory(child.title);
          let setExternalId = await categoryService.setExternalId(createCategory.body.version, createCategory.body.id, child.categoryid);
          let changeParent = await categoryService.changeParent(setExternalId.body.version, setExternalId.body.id, setExternalIdRoot.body.id)
          await createTree(child, changeParent.body.id);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  } 
}
```

As you can understand, I need to perform 3 operations on every `child` (create the element category, set an external id attribute and set the parent) and then, only when the `child` category is created, call the *createTree* function recursively also on its children, passing its id.
The problem is that I'm not able to do this asynchronously. Sometimes the kids are created before the parent is ready so I receive an error.
Can you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

ps. yes all the functions are `async function` promises.

Comment: you have a return inside a for loop - the for loop will never run more than once

Comment: ok I removed it, the function is running, but is creating only the first layer of categories. It's not running recursively on kids.

Comment: well, at least that's one problem solved

Comment: That `if (rootCategory.children.category.length > 0)` is pointless, your loop condition already does check that.

Comment: "*Sometimes the kids are created before the parent is ready so I receive an error.*" - uh, no. Your code is entirely sequential, this will work fine. Maybe some of the called functions resolve their returned promises before they are done? Probably there are some bugs inside the code you haven't posted.

Comment: An obvious problem with your code is that 3 operations are not performed on the `rootCategory` itself. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @Bergi it's like a tree. I have to create the parent (3 operations: create, set external id and set parent) then I can cycle on kids. So every kid to be created in the correct way need the id of the parent.

Comment: @sharkbait OK, so the root node is not supposed to be affected by that because it has no parent? Then that part is fine.